# Select the current and previous rows per client in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have the dataframe as below and I want to extract the rows for each client where Flag = 1 and the previous row (if it exists) for the same client. For example, row number 1 (I start from 1, not 0), 2,3,6,7,8,10,11,12

```
   report_date  customer_id           Flag 

01/01/20                1               0
02/01/20                1               1
03/01/20                1               1
04/01/20                1               0
05/01/20                1               0
01/01/20                2               0
02/01/20                2               1
03/01/20                2               1
04/01/20                2               0
01/01/20                3               0
02/01/20                3               1     
03/01/20                3               1
04/01/20                3               0
05/01/20                3               0
06/01/20                3               0
07/01/20                3               0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for shifting values per groups and compare with `1` and chain by compare not shifted column by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df['prev'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['Flag'].shift(-1).eq(1) | df['Flag'].eq(1)
df['next'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['Flag'].shift().eq(1) | df['Flag'].eq(1)
print (df)
   report_date  customer_id  Flag   prev   next
0     01/01/20            1     0   True  False
1     02/01/20            1     1   True   True
2     03/01/20            1     1   True   True
3     04/01/20            1     0  False   True
4     05/01/20            1     0  False  False
5     01/01/20            2     0   True  False
6     02/01/20            2     1   True   True
7     03/01/20            2     1   True   True
8     04/01/20            2     0  False   True
9     01/01/20            3     0   True  False
10    02/01/20            3     1   True   True
11    03/01/20            3     1   True   True
12    04/01/20            3     0  False   True
13    05/01/20            3     0  False  False
14    06/01/20            3     0  False  False
15    07/01/20            3     0  False  False
```